# Gram determinant and linearly independence

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm stuck in the "$\Longrightarrow$" of the following question.

> **Exercise**. Let $f_1,...,f_n\colon X\to\Bbb{K}$ functions defined on an arbitrary set $X$, where $\Bbb{K}$ is a field. Show that $(f_j)_{j=1}^n$ is a linearly independent family of $\Bbb{K}^X$ if and only if there exists $x_1,...,x_n\in X$ such that $$\det\left[\begin{array}{ccc}f_1(x_1)&\cdots&f_n(x_1)\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\f_1(x_n)&\cdots&f_n(x_n)\end{array}\right]\ne0$$

The part "$\Longleftarrow$" is pretty simple, but the another implication...
My colegues tells me that we can prove by induction on $n$, this seems ok to me. But, anyone there has some another idea? Thanks for any help!

Comment: If $X$ is a finite set, this amounts to the observation that [determinantal rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Alternative_definitions) coincides with the usual rank

Comment: By the way, this is not what is typically referred to as a "Gram determinant".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom in fact, I just wrote "gram determinant" there because my teacher gives this tittle to the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $(f_i)$ is a linearly independent family.  That is, for any coefficients $c_1,\dots,c_n$ not all equal to zero, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $\sum_{i}c_i f_i(x) \neq 0$.

Let $F:X \to \Bbb K^n$ denote the map $x \mapsto (f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x))$ (which I will take to be a column-vector, for the purposes of computation).  Now, suppose $(f_i)$ is a linearly independent family.  That is, for every vector $c = (c_1,\dots,c_n) \in \Bbb K^n$, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $c^TF(x) \neq 0$.  Thus, the span of the vectors $\{F(x) : x \in X\}$ satisfies 
$$
\operatorname{span}(\{F(x) : x \in X\})^\perp = \{0\}.
$$
Thus, $\operatorname{span}(\{F(x) : x \in X\}) = \Bbb K^n$.  Thus, there exist $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that the vectors $F(x_1), \dots, F(x_n)$ are linearly independent.  If we take these vectors $F(x_1), \dots, F(x_n)$, then we find that this matrix is square and must have a non-zero determinant, as desired.